# Socket data with python and powershell

Tags: python, powershell, sockets, encoding

I have a server in Python running on Linux.
My client is Powershell running on Windows.

I'm sending result data of a system command from Powershell to Linux.

However, I have an encoding problem, but I don't know where, because on Linux all accent are not displayed.

Here is my powershell code sending data :

```
$response = GetOutput $tcpStream
$return = Invoke-Expression $response
$return = $return -join "`r`n"

$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$data = $enc.GetBytes($return)

$writer.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
$writer.WriteLine($data)
$writer.Flush()
```

Here is my python code receiving the data :

```
data = client.recv(PacketSize)
data = data[:-15]
if not data:
    break
data = data.encode('utf-8')
print("%s") % data
```

Is anyone know where is the encoding problem ?

Comment: What's the error/problem? What _Python_ version are you using? `encode`/`decode` are inverse counterparts meaning that each does the exact opposite of the other (`s == decode(encode(s))`). So, in order to have the same result at both ends, you should call each function in one of the ends. I'm not sure what the _PS_ code does (encodes/decodes), but I feel (might be wrong) that on _Python_ side you should decode.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. The problem is that special characters are not displayed properly on my linux. I tried with decode, and the result is absolutly the same :(. I think the problem might come with the Powershell encoding part but I don't know what I should use to encode :(

Comment: I don't know if I can do this, but this comment is to make an "UP".

Comment: The character might be incorrectly **displayed**, or incorrect itself (indicating an encode/decode problem). On *Python* side you should print the *ASCII* code of each char in the stream, and check the ones displayed incorrectly. Also, did you try printing the chars from *PS*? Yo should also provide some input sample, an expected (which should be the input) and actual output in order to be easier to debug.